# HTML/CSS Mystery? Can't figure where the size is called up

Tags: css, html, width, styling

I've been asked to try and modify a page for use elsewhere.

Basically everything I've done apart from a single mystery which I cannot solve.

The page I'm basing off is https://wombatservers.com.au/theburrow

Notice the big image at the top depicting a minecraft world. Well basically I can't have it filling the whole width of the screen (it needs to be a specific size in the other project). But I can't for the life of me find where this is controlled at all, the same for the blue footer at the bottom.

So if anyone could help me track down which line(s) the widths of these elements are called that'd be great.

(I'm expecting this to be a really obvious thing I've overlooked)

Thanks

Comment: style.css:59 `background: url(../images/slide1.jpg) center center repeat-x;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following css adds the image:

```
.pager {
  background: url(../images/slide1.jpg) center center repeat-x;
  padding: 50px 0 50px 0;
}
```

The html looks like this:

```
<div class="pager">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="pager-title l">
      <h1>The Burrow</h1>
      <p>Tutorials, lessons, resources and a whole lot more!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="test-text r">
      <h2>By far the best Aussie host I've ever used! No lag at all!<img src="images/bulate2.png" alt="" style="position:relative; margin-left:10px; margin-top:-15px;"></h2> 
      <p>— Jeremy, <a href="#">EmuCraft Australia</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="c"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You probably want to put pager div inside the wrapper div like so:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="pager">
    <div class="pager-title l">
      <h1>The Burrow</h1>
      <p>Tutorials, lessons, resources and a whole lot more!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="test-text r">
      <h2>By far the best Aussie host I've ever used! No lag at all!<img src="images/bulate2.png" alt="" style="position:relative; margin-left:10px; margin-top:-15px;"></h2> 
      <p>— Jeremy, <a href="#">EmuCraft Australia</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="c"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or something like that, but then you will have to do the same with the footer.

Comment: Perfect thank you! I knew it'd be something obvious like that

Answer (score 0):

Both pictures a backgrounds and since there is no background-size property set, the browser just uses the complete width of the image file and crops it where the html object ends. So the width of the header picture is 1600px and of the footer is 1169px. But the shown size depends on your viewport width.